# Configure logback.xml to split logs based on packages without overlapping information

Tags: java, logback

I want to log everything of a package *a* into the logfile *a.loq* and all the rest (without any logs of *a*) into the *standard.log* file. So far I have got the *a.log* file but the standard log is still conaining everything of package *a*.

```
<logger name="my.package.a" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-A"/>
</logger>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-STD"/>
</root>
```

Comment: _logger has its additivity flag set to false such that its logging output will be sent to the appender named FILE but not to any appender attached **higher** in the hierarchy._ from [doc](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html). Maybe it's about ordering of appenders and loggers.

Comment: indeed it seems to be an ordering issue - thx! you want to provide your comment as answer?

Comment: glad to help you. Yep, I provided it as answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From [documentation](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html):

> logger has its additivity flag set to false such that its logging output will be sent to the appender named FILE but not to any appender attached **higher** in the hierarchy

So, it's all about ordering of appenders and loggers in your *logback.xml*.

Appenders should be declared **higher** than this logger.

Answer (score 0):

According with how the log4j works, it will log everything that matches the filter into the file.
But the root logger will still log all related "INFO" from all the sources....

So its not possible to remove from the root logger this behavior. What you can do is: put something more detailed for the filter and interchange both. 
Like below:

```
<logger name="my.package.a" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-A"/>
</logger>

<root level="WARN">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-STD"/>
</root>
```